# How can I combine Date Vectors with different lenghts in R?

Tags: r

I have the following 3 vectors:

```
a <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), to= as.Date("2016-01-01"), by = "year")
b <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2009-02-01"), to= as.Date("2016-02-01"), by = "year")
c <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-11-15"), to= as.Date("2013-11-15"), by = "year")
```

And the following list:

```
l <- list(a,b,c)
```

Now I would like to build a Dataframe. I tried something like that:

```
d <- data.frame(sapply(l,"[",seq(max(sapply(l,length)))))
d[is.na(d)] <- 0
```

However, the data frame now only consists of numbers.

```
 X1    X2    X3
1 14610 14276 14928
2 14975 14641 15293
3 15340 15006 15659
4 15706 15371 16024
5 16071 15737     0
6 16436 16102     0
7 16801 16467     0
8     0 16832     0
```

I tried as.Date to fix this but it didn't work.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I'd like to have the table/data frame with Dates ("2010-01-01") and not with numbers.

Comment: Change `sapply` to `lapply`.

Comment: and maybe name also the list like `l <- list(X1=a,X2=b,X3=c)`

Comment: and maybe also change to `d[is.na(d)] <- as.Date("0-1-1")`. But what is the intention of this?